# Making sure string numbers operations are culture independent

Tags: string, vba, excel, double

I download an exchange rate through an `XmlHttp` request that gets inside the code as a `string` (being the `.innerText` of a `<div>` element) and represents a `double` type number: `1.525`.

When building this script, I've done it on my OS which has the English culture model (i.e. `1.525` means 1 unit and 0.525 decimals). 
However, this script will now run on a French OS which uses the comma `,` instead of the `.` to separate decimals.

Which means, the operation `Application.Evaluate(10000/myRate)` will fail if the `.` is instead of the `,`.

Easy solution would be to replace the "." with a "," via `Application.Evaluate(10000/Replace(myRate,".",",")`. However, this is clearly not nice because now the script would fail on an English system.

With `VB.NET` I would be able to make it culture-independent by converting it like:

```
myRate.ToDouble(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I've tried Googling the VBA alternative for a while without success; does anyone know if there's a more elegant way of internationalize my script than just replacing the "." with a ","?

Here's my current solution (that I don't really like):

```
On Error Resume Next
test = CDbl(myRate)/2
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    myRate = Replace(myRate,".",",")
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `Application.DecimalSeparator` property?

```
Application.Evaluate(10000/CDbl(Replace(myRate,".", Application.DecimalSeparator))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can temporary change decimal and thousands separator, by using Application object.

To read several current OS (International) settings: [Application.International(index) property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840213.aspx)

To change:

```
Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
```

Comment: Nice as well (especially to know), but I prefer the solution of SO as it makes all in a line and makes as well 100% sure the conversion without the need of changing the Application properties :)

Comment: OK, appreciate this ;)

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, we do not have `Application.DecimalSeparator` nor `Application.ThousandsSeparator` nor `Application.International`. The only thing we have is `Val(vString)` and `Str(vNumber)`. They both convert the argument using the English (invariant) culture.

So, in MS Access the OP's question could be solved like this:

```
vResult = 10000/Val(myRate)
```